# How to say "we didn't have fun there" in French ?

Tags: pronoms, négation, passé-composé, imparfait

> Nous sommes allés à la piscine.

I then want to say that we didn't have fun there because the water was too cold.

Can I say:

> Nous n'allons pas eu nous amuser parce que l'eau était trop froide.

But how to add *there* in that sentence ?

Answer (score 6):

> Nous ne nous y sommes pas amusés.

En terme de concordance des temps, il est important que tu aies le même dans tes deux phrases (passé composé donc). L'usage du futur tel que tu le fais n'a pas de sens. Ensuite, le "there" est traduit simplement par "y", ce qui est à mon sens la solution la plus élégante.

I don't know if I should write this answer in French or in English, so I write them both. First, it is important that the time in both your sentences is the same. Using the future like you did makes no sense. Next, "there" translates into "y", which is the more elegant way in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

Formal proposition that also stays quite close to the English sentence:

> Nous sommes allés à la piscine, mais nous ne nous y sommes pas amusés car l'eau était trop froide

To be clear, "y" refers to "la piscine", hence the second part of the sentence is equivalent to:

> nous ne nous sommes pas amusés à la piscine car ...

In an oral conversation, especially a casual one, you probably wouldn't bother with pronouncing "nous ne nous y sommes ..." and you could go for something like:

> Nous sommes allés à la piscine, mais l'eau était trop froide et nous ne nous sommes pas amusés

Answer (score 3):

*Nous* as a subject is rarely used in spoken French so you will often hear something like :

> On [ne] s'est pas amusés à la piscine parce que l'eau était trop froide.

A more formal/written way would be:

> Nous ne nous sommes pas amusés à la piscine car l'eau [y] était trop froide.

Comment: That's probably something of a troll subject, but do we really want to encourage the replacement of "nous" by "on" on the basis of the fact that most French people have forgotten our never learnt to use "nous" properly?

Comment: @AlexHalm I am not encouraging (or discouraging either) people to use "on" vs "nous". I'm just reporting a well known fact. In any case, if there is a cause, it is a lost one, the ratio being probably (wild guess) 95% "on" vs 5% "nous" in spoken French.

Answer (score 3):

L'usage compte autant que la traduction littérale. [*Nous ne nous y sommes pas amusés*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13658/343) est tout à fait correct, et même employé. C'est cependant une tournure soit très formelle, soit un peu scolaire. Au quotidien, il est courant, en ce genre de situation, de qualifier l'activité elle-même plutôt que le ressenti que l'on en a:

> Ce n'était pas amusant (car l'eau était trop froide).
>   *It wasn't funny (because the water was too cold).*

Cela sonne plus naturel à mes oreilles.

Le *nous* est suggéré par le fait de qualifier l'activité: la phrase décrit un ressenti, celui que *nous* avons.

Le *there*, objet de la question, est également implicite. Il est induit par *ce*, employé sous la forme suivante :<sup>[TLF, I.-A.-1.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce)</sup>

> Quelque chose de précis qui vient d'être dit ou qui va l'être

*Ce* signifie "être allé à la piscine", et indique donc le lieu que l'on voudrait identifier par *there*, en anglais.

---

[*Nous ne nous y sommes pas amusés*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13658/343) is absolutely correct, and is used. In terms of usage however, it sounds either quite formal or a bit academic. In such a situation, it is common that we qualify the activity itself rather than how we appreciate it:

> Ce n'était pas amusant (car l'eau était trop froide).
>   *It wasn't funny (because the water was too cold).*

This sounds more natural to me.

*Nous* is implied by the fact we qualify the activity: this expresses a feeling, the feeling that *we* have.

*There* (subject of the question) is also implied. It is suggested by *ce*, defined as follows:<sup>[TLF, I.-A.-1.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce)</sup>

> Quelque chose de précis qui vient d'être dit ou qui va l'être

*Ce* stands for "être allé à la piscine", and therefore identifies the swimming pool.

Comment: Excellent et dans les deux langues!

Comment: +1 because others answers look too formal compared with the question

Answer (score -3):

Nous ne sommes pas bien amusés là-bas.

Comment: "nous ne NOUS sommes pas bien amusés"